# Adding DateTime to filename during rename

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have found lots of examples of people creating new files and adding the current Datetime then the file extension but what I want to do is look to see if a file currently exists and if it does simply add the current DateTime to the file name but I can't figure out how to maintain the file extension. My current code so far:

```
public class FileUploadHelper
{
    private CoreSiteContext db = new CoreSiteContext();

    public Int64 UploadSiteImage(string ContainerName, string NewFileName, HttpPostedFile UploadedFile)
    {
        string SavePath = @"F:\FFInfoImages\" + ContainerName + @"\";

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(SavePath + NewFileName))
        {
            System.IO.File.Move(SavePath + NewFileName, SavePath + NewFileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_ss"));
            UploadedFile.SaveAs(SavePath + NewFileName);
        }
        else
        {
            UploadedFile.SaveAs(SavePath + NewFileName);
        }

        using (db)
        {
            File NewFile = new File()
            {
                FileName = NewFileName,
                ContentType = UploadedFile.ContentType
            };

            db.Files.Add(NewFile);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return NewFile.ID;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appears as if the NewFileName string variable does not get passed in with the filename extension, otherwise most of this should work. Why not get the extension from UploadedFile?

```
string strNewPath = SavePath + NewFileName + Path.GetExtension(UploadedFile.FileName);

if (System.IO.File.Exists(strNewPath)) {
  System.IO.File.Move(strNewPath, SavePath + NewFileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_ss") + Path.GetExtension(UploadedFile.FileName));
  UploadedFile.SaveAs(strNewPath);
}
else {
  UploadedFile.SaveAs(strNewPath);
}

using (db) {
  File NewFile = new File() {
    FileName = NewFileName + Path.GetExtension(UploadedFile.FileName),
    ContentType = UploadedFile.ContentType
  };

  db.Files.Add(NewFile);
  db.SaveChanges();

  return NewFile.ID;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

.NET has built-in methods for safely extracting the different portions of a file name (the file's name and it's extension, respectively). `Path` exists in the `System.IO` namespace.

- [Path.GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Assuming `NewFileName` is something like `myfilename.txt`, you could use it like this (untested):

```
if (File.Exists(SavePath + NewFileName))
{
    var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(NewFileName);
    var ext = Path.GetExtension(NewFileName);

    File.Move(SavePath + NewFileName,
        SavePath + name + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_ss") + ext);
}
UploadedFile.SaveAs(SavePath + NewFileName);
```

Comment: The plan is to have `NewFileName` passed in without a file extention attached to it as I was hoping to pull it off the UploadedFile.

Comment: I just realized that problem as I was looking over the code you provided. I was hoping to pull the extension off the `UploadedFile` but I think I now need to re examine my whole approach.

Comment: I just saw his and it looks to be working to fix the root issues of grabbing the extension of the uploaded file. Tanks for your input though it both put me on the right path and revealed an underlining problem.

Answer (score 2):

The following method totally solves your problem

```
System.IO.Path.GetExtension("Path");
```

You'd better get the current file name without extension first using `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("Path")` then add the Date Time and then add up the extension anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Path.GetExtension()` method to identify the file extension.

Try This:

```
   String strExtension=IO.Path.GetExtension(SavePath + NewFileName);  
   if (System.IO.File.Exists(SavePath + NewFileName))
    {
        System.IO.File.Move(SavePath + NewFileName, SavePath + NewFileName +  DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_ss")+strExtension);
        UploadedFile.SaveAs(SavePath + NewFileName);
    }
    else
    {
        UploadedFile.SaveAs(SavePath + NewFileName);
    }
```

Comment: @GrantWinney: yes Zec is the one who told `Path.GetExtention(UploadedFile.FileName)` works. Thanks for your remainder.

Comment: Thanks for point that out. SO has a habit of rearranging the answers and where his was got replaced with yours.